# Unity: White outline around seams in my character, make it stop!

Tags: unity, textures, rendering, uv-mapping, image-processing

so once upon a time I made a really cool character for my game project and he looked great. Then at some unspecific point in time, my character's UV seams got these awful white outlines around them:

[image]

I assumed the problem was that during some texture revision, I didn't paint past the island seams, so I compared the texture file with an image of the UV output, but in fact I did paint past the seams, so that isn't the problem. I have heard that this may have something to do with antialiasing, but I don't want to turn that off if I can fix the problem another way. Also, notice that the enemy character in the above gif does not suffer from the same problem.

What could be causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: That feels more like a mipmapping problem, than an antialiasing one

Comment: Thank you @Bálint, turning off mipmaps solved my problem. Please make this an Answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines around texture seems aren't usually caused by anti aliasing, since that's only doing multiple passes per fragment. If it isn't visible without anti aliasing, it won't be visible after either.

Texture problems are instead usually caused by mipmapping. It can make the seams a lot more imprecise.

Comment: This answer could be improved by showing some way to avoid that problem without having to resort to switching off mip mapping altogether.

Comment: It's been suggested elsewhere on the internet that changing the interpolation mode (i.e. from "box" to "linear") can improve image quality while being more computationally expensive.

I am going to experiment with this on some of my static meshes. My camera is orthographic and the angle does not change, so static meshes look very good almost everywhere thanks to consistent orientation, with the exception of where those meshes meet the background.